# Is reversing a linked list better by using stacks?

Tags: java, list, stack, reverse

I was reversing a singly linked list using the following code:

```
Node prevNode = null;
Node currNode = head;
while (currNode != null) {
    Node next = currNode.next;
    currNode.next = prevNode;
    prevNode = currNode;
    currNode = next;
}
head = prevNode;
```

Then when I was going through some material about stacks it suggested that reversing any list is best done by using a stack.

It is for sure very easy to visualize that we indeed pop out the elements and push them into a new stack and in the end it is essentially reversed. But which of the two methods is better or would take lesser time?

Comment: One uses O(1) additional space, the other uses O(n) additional space. You decide which is better.

Comment: O(1) would be better for sure. But then is stack recommended for reversing to be better due to easy visualization only?

Comment: The industry-standard way is to use `Collections.reverse()`. For practice, everything that teaches you something is recommended. So do both and learn even more :)

Comment: Interesting. Will surely implement stack to reverse linked list :)

Comment: Be careful not to "overly optimise" when writing code. Machines are performant enough now that we don't need to press every last cycle... The readability of code also has merit - and I wouldn't write a slightly faster routine if the impact of that was to make the routine less obvious to another developer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reversing I guess it means making the **links** between two elements opposite to what it previously was i.e. if it was `1->2->3->4` then it is now `1<-2<-3<-4`.

The **best way** to do it is by breaking this list into two parts namely *current* and *rest*, it is a recursive approach.

**Time Complexity: O(n), 
Space Complexity: O(1)**

`1->2->3->4`

---

`1->2->3<-4` (4 being the rest)

---

`1->2<-3<-4`

---

`1<-2<-3<-4`

You can find the details of this approach here: [enter link description here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-reverse-the-nodes-of-a-linked-list/)

Answer (score 2):

An in-place reversing is always better than using a stack, because we are not using any additional space.  However, for an immutable list, the only option to reverse is to use to stack too.